# Contenedor redimensionable con overflow y elementos dentro usando Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Tengo una plantilla de pantalla maquetada con Bootstrap 4 con menú, cabecera, cuerpo y pie de pagina dividida de la siguiente manera:

```
"******************************************" 
"*      *          CABECERA               *"
"*      ***********************************"
"*      *          CUERPO                 *"
"*      *                                 *"
"*      *   Titulo 1                      *"
"*      *   Boton 1                       *"
"*      *                                 *"
"* MENU *   ****************************  *"
"*      *   * Contenedor 1             *  *"
"*      *   *                          *  *"
"*      *   ****************************  *"
"*      *                                 *"
"*      ***********************************"
"*      *          PIE                    *"
"******************************************"
```

Dentro de "Contenedor 1" voy colocando unos elementos o ítems que según el alto o ancho de la ventana del navegador me los va colocando en horizontal o en columna.
El problema que tengo es que cuando la cantidad de elementos dentro del "Contenedor 1" es grande este tiene una altura mayor a la de la ventana que la contiene y entonces desaparece de la ventana visible la cabecera, el "titulo 1", "Boton 1" y el pie de pagina.

Lo que me interesaría es que este contenedor tuviera un overflow en y con scroll para que estos elementos se vieran dentro del contenedor sin salir de el.
Además el "Contenedor 1" debería tener una altura máxima entre Boton 1 y pie que variaría según el tamaño de la ventana visible.

El código que tengo puesto para el overflow no me funciona. En la  parte del cuerpo tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
   <a href="#"><span>Boton 1</span></a>
   <div id="Contenedor1" class="row" style="background-color: red; overflow-y: scroll;">
   <!-- Contenido que se agrega dinámicamente -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vas a necesitar ponerle un 'height' fijo al contenedor del scroll y además creo que deberías, si la estructura es como planteas en el gráfico de arriba, incluir un div con 'col' dentro del row.

Comment: @JorgeGuz el height del contenedor es lo que hay entre botón 1 y pie pero además este height debe ser variable dinamicamente cada vez que redimensione la ventana del navegador, o según el dispositivo donde se vea. Agregando max-height: me hace el overflow auto.¿ Pero como vario la altura cuando redimensiono el contenedor?

Comment: Poniéndolo en porcentaje por ejemplo y usando las media-query que te permitirán cambiar este tamaño bien sea en px bien % para cada breakpoint que te haga falta.

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco para que oferflow-y funcione tiene que tener una altura determinada. SI no, dicho div irá aumentando su height a medida  que añadas contenido.

Lo he puesto una altura en PX como ejemplo.

Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta.  Es que row, añade flex en columnas. Si quieres filas, tienes que añadirle la clase `d-block` o bien `col-12` a cada uno de los items de contenido que añadas dinámicamente.

PD: También he modificado `overflow-y: sroll` a `overflow-y: auto`, ya que entiendo que si la altura es suficiente, no quiere mostrar la barrita para hacer scroll.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:60vh;">
       <div class="row"><h1>Titulo 1</h1></div>
       <div class="row"><a href="#"><span>Boton 1</span></a></div>
       <div id="Contenedor1" class="row d-block h-75" style="background-color: red; overflow-y: auto;">
           <!-- Contenido que se agrega dinámicamente -->
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Con max-height funciona correcto ! Pero ¿ Como hago para que la altura del contenedor ocupe el espacio entre botón 1 y pie de pagina.? Teniendo en cuenta que esta altura siempre será variable dependiendo del dispositivo o ventana del navegador.

Comment: usa los atributos bottom y top eso lo fija a los extremos superior e inferior de la ventana, pero necesitas mediaquerys para establecer la altura acorde con las ventanas de los dispositivos

Comment: @Popularfan puedes usar style="height: 20%" .. .30% etc

O usar las variables de boostrap h-25,h-50,h-75,h-100 

PEro algun elemento debe tener altura fija antes... he actualizado mir espuesta poniendo el container fluid con altura fija como ejemplo.

Comment: @quevedo como pongo los atributos bottom y top? Te refieres al css del contenedor ?

Comment: Hola @Popularfan los atributos bottom y top se usan para posicionamiento, (por ej de elementos div) y establecen la distancia a los bordes asignando un valor que puede ser en **pixels**, porcentual o en unidades como **em**, etc. Si asignas bottom: 0; fijas distancia cero al borde inferior ...
Referencia [Bottom property en W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#propdef-bottom)

Comment: @quevedo antes tengo que dar un valor de altura al contenedor. Tendria que poner bottom 0 + el alto del pie y top el bottom del boton 1. Pero esto debe haber  alguna instrucion en bootstrap o css que lo haga automatico sin hacer calculos en javascript

Comment: te voy a agregar una respuesta pequeña que ilustra el manejo de los atributos

Answer (score 1):

### Cómo abarcar una parte fija de la pantalla con independencia del dispositivo

En especificación de W3C [Visual formatting model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html) se encuentra la documentación necesaria para complementar las ideas que se presentan aquí.

Según dices necesitas que un contenedor abarque gran parte de la altura de la ventana visible y que se presente un scroller a su derecha en caso de que el contenido desborde su altura. Para ello basta con ajustar su posicionamiento relativo usando un juego de atributos:

1. Para que el contenedor este fijo establecer position: fixed;
2. Para fijar distancias a los bordes usar los atributos top, bottom, left, right indicando los valores de las distancias así valor_numerico unidad_de_medida, donde valor_numerico es un número (no necesarianente entero) y unidad de medida un sufijo descriptor como **px** (pixels), **%** (porcentaje), **em** (relativo el tamaño de fuente), etc.
3. En tu caso necesitas usar el juego con valor bottom: 0;
4. Establecer el atributo overflow-y = auto; para tener el scroller.

Ahora voy a agregar un pequeño ejemplo con contenido desbordante pero, con otras dimensiones para que puedas ver el uso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <h4>Ejemplo de scroller vertical en contenedor fijo</h4>
    <div style="
      position: fixed;
      top: 300px;
      left: 100px;
      right: 100px;
      bottom: 100px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    ">
    Sed iure Mucius. ego autem mirari [satis] non queo unde hoc sit tam insolens domesticarum rerum fastidium. non est omnino hic docendi locus; sed ita sentio et saepe disserui, Latinam linguam non modo non inopem, ut vulgo putarent, sed locupletiorem etiam esse quam Graecam. quando enim nobis, vel dicam aut oratoribus bonis aut poetis, postea quidem quam fuit quem imitarentur, ullus orationis vel copiosae vel elegantis ornatus defuit? Ego vero, quoniam forensibus operis, laboribus, periculis non deseruisse mihi videor praesidium, in quo a populo Romano locatus sum, debeo profecto, quantumcumque possum, in eo quoque elaborare, ut sint opera, studio, labore meo doctiores cives mei, nec cum istis tantopere pugnare, qui Graeca legere malint, modo legant illa ipsa, ne simulent, et iis servire, qui vel utrisque litteris uti velint vel, si suas habent, illas non magnopere desiderent.

Qui autem alia malunt scribi a nobis, aequi esse debent, quod et scripta multa sunt, sic ut plura nemini e nostris, et scribentur fortasse plura, si vita suppetet; et tamen, qui diligenter haec, quae de philosophia litteris mandamus, legere assueverit, iudicabit nulla ad legendum his esse potiora. quid est enim in vita tantopere quaerendum quam cum omnia in philosophia, tum id, quod his libris quaeritur, qui sit finis, quid extremum, quid ultimum, quo sint omnia bene vivendi recteque faciendi consilia referenda, quid sequatur natura ut summum ex rebus expetendis, quid fugiat ut extremum malorum? qua de re cum sit inter doctissimos summa dissensio, quis alienum putet eius esse dignitatis, quam mihi quisque tribuat, quid in omni munere vitae optimum et verissimum sit, exquirere?

An, partus ancillae sitne in fructu habendus, disseretur inter principes civitatis, P. Scaevolam M'.que Manilium, ab iisque M. Brutus dissentiet -- quod et acutum genus est et ad usus civium non inutile, nosque ea scripta reliquaque eiusdem generis et legimus libenter et legemus --, haec, quae vitam omnem continent, neglegentur? nam, ut sint illa vendibiliora, haec uberiora certe sunt. quamquam id quidem licebit iis existimare, qui legerint. nos autem hanc omnem quaestionem de finibus bonorum et malorum fere a nobis explicatam esse his litteris arbitramur, in quibus, quantum potuimus, non modo quid nobis probaretur, sed etiam quid a singulis philosophiae disciplinis diceretur, persecuti sumus.

Ut autem a facillimis ordiamur, prima veniat in medium Epicuri ratio, quae plerisque notissima est. quam a nobis sic intelleges eitam, ut ab ipsis, qui eam disciplinam probant, non soleat accuratius explicari; verum enim invenire volumus, non tamquam adversarium aliquem convincere. accurate autem quondam a L. Torquato, homine omni doctrina erudito, defensa est Epicuri sententia de voluptate, a meque ei responsum, cum C. Triarius, in primis gravis et doctus adolescens, ei disputationi interesset.

Nam cum ad me in Cumanum salutandi causa uterque venisset, pauca primo inter nos de litteris, quarum summum erat in utroque studium, deinde Torquatus: Quoniam nacti te, inquit, sumus aliquando otiosum, certe audiam, quid sit, quod Epicurum nostrum non tu quidem oderis, ut fere faciunt, qui ab eo dissentiunt, sed certe non probes, eum quem ego arbitror unum vidisse verum maximisque erroribus animos hominum liberavisse et omnia tradidisse, quae pertinerent ad bene beateque vivendum. sed existimo te, sicut nostrum Triarium, minus ab eo delectari, quod ista Platonis, Aristoteli, Theophrasti orationis ornamenta neglexerit. nam illud quidem adduci vix possum, ut ea, quae senserit ille, tibi non vera videantur.
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Le integré un montón de texto para asegurar que desborde la altura cuando lo pruebes.

Va a aparecer una marco fijo con scroller a derecha. Notaras que el contenedor se estira abarcando la pantalla si lo pruebas asignando un color de fondo y con poco contenido.